# Python why my modules stopped working after changing version of Python on Windows?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, module, scikit-learn

I had my modules installed and working (anaconda and much more), then I was required to change the version of my Python for installing tensor-flow. I did it and changed the version to 3.5.2 and installed the proper version of tensor-flow which works on windows. However, all my other modules stopped working even though they are properly installed. Why does it happen? Is it related to the fact I change the environment variables? I am sorry for this question but I found only related topics which discuss Linux and not Windows.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please be more specific: 1. What version of Python did you use before? 2. How did you change to 3.5.2? 3. What do you mean by 'stop working' and 'properly installed'? Do you get error messages? Which? How do you know they are properly installed?

Comment: 1) probably 2.7 but I am not sure it can be also 3.4. 
2) I simply downloaded from the site and clicked the icon which makes in installation. The error which I receive is for example "ImportError: No module named 'matplotlib'"
3) BTW, it includes numpy OK, but for example it doesn't include sklearn well...

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you used python 2.X before.
In that case you need to reinstall your dependencies for python 3.5, since python 2 and python 3 are not compatible.

You mentioned anaconda. There is a python3 distribution of anaconda that you should use.

Here are some lists what the differences are:

[Official 3.0 changes](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html)

[A user compiled list](http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_python_2_3_key_diff.html)

This is also not a OS specific problem, it doesn't matter if you upgrade your python distribution on windows or linux.

Comment: OK, it maybe right if I am not wrong I used 2.7 (but I am not sure). However, what should I do? which command should I enter into the prompt?

Comment: There is no command. You need to refactor your code to be compatible with changes introduced in python3. It's not quite possible to do this automatically. Here you can download anaconda for python3 https://www.continuum.io/downloads, the changes in your own code you will have to make yourself.